# How to find a developer release on MetaCPAN?

Tags: perl, metacpan

Is it possible to find a module on [MetaCPAN](https://metacpan.org/) if the module is only available as developer release?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you know where to look. You need to know the author's CPAN ID, the distribution name, and the version number. The URL takes the form:

```
https://metacpan.org/release/${author}/${dist}-${version}
```

An example is https://metacpan.org/release/TOBYINK/Types-DateTime-0.000_01. I have just uploaded this developer release, and at the time of me writing this answer, the distribution has not yet had a stable release.

You won't find it in the search; you won't find it in author listings. But it's there. It'll show up in the "Recent" listings. You can even favourite it.